# "We're both" or "both of us"?

Tags: grammar

For example:

• We're both 20.

Or

• (The) both of us are 20.

I don't mean to include the person I'm talking to. Which one is more appropriate?

Comment: "We are both..." and "both of us are..." are equivalent. Neither phrase, by itself, excludes the person you are telling.

Comment: "the both of us" is an excellent example of trailer trash speech. Right up there with: We might could do it. Ah, the wonders of language, eh? If this type of speech is scorned, many Hollywood scripts would have to be scrapped. I encourage all non-native VVS (Very Advanced Speakers) to learn it.

Answer (score 2):

Both

> We are twenty

and

> Both of us are 20

are grammatically correct and appropriate. Using the option with *the* sounds terribly old fashioned and non-idiomatic.

The hearer understands that 'both' does not include him/her by the context and discernment of the speaker's intention.